# sync select list with custom dropdown placeholder

Tags: jquery

I have a custom dropdown with an underlying select list. It works like Amazon's search scope selector. Currently I 'sync' the custom dropdown with the select list like this:
(prev() is the custom element)

```
var $select = $('select');
$select.each(function(index, value) {
  var newValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(newValue);
});

$('select').change(function() {
  var newValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(newValue);
});
```

The code works fine and takes care of presetting the custom dropdown element on page load and on change(). However, I would like to learn how to do this in a better way - can I for instance maintain the sync using on() somehow?

Comment: Questions involving refactoring working code should be posted to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

I got this from codereview

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(optionText);
}).trigger('change');
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20976/maintain-sync-of-select-list